# A bone is not being keyframed

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, rigify

When I hit I on the parameters it says this  "F-Curve with path 'pose. Bones["torso"].location[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkgXn.jpg)' cannot be keyframed, ensure that it is not locked or sampled, and try removing F-Modifiers" Here I've linked the model from another blend file. I checked it in the original file, nothing wrong there. Also its not locked and I don't know what sampled means but I don't think I've done anything. Also it's in a keying set. It'll be a really big help if you can solve this. Everything was alright yesterday, but I'm facing this problem today. Except for the Z location other parameters are not getting keyframed. Even though they are in the keying set. I tried without the keying set but doesn't work.
[image: Only Z loc is keyframed]

Comment: Hello could you please share the armature only and tell what bone can't be keyframed?